# Coefficient bias in ARIMA vs. lagged regression

Tags: arima, bias, lm, lags

I am trying to estimate the effect of an external regressor $x_t$ on a time series $y_t$. 
My first attempt was using an ARIMAX(p,d,q) Model to estimate $\beta_x$ while controlling for the ARMA structure in the errors.

In a second attempt, I modeled $y_t$ using a linear OLS model which includes $y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, ..., y_{t-p}$ as lagged predictors. The estimates I am getting for $\beta_x$ are quite different between the two approaches.

From a theoretical point, the OLS model with lagged predictors should produce similar results as an AR-model (neglecting optimizations issues). Hence the difference must lay in the MA-part of the ARIMA model (neglecting the differentiation for a moment).

So on a general level, under which conditions should I expect to obtain biased estimates of $x_t$ from a linear OLS model?

Best,
W.

Comment: The difference and/or similarity between the models might be less obvious than you might think. Check out Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference and/or similarity between the models might be less obvious than you might think. Check out Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

> My first attempt was using an ARIMAX(p,d,q) Model to estimate $\beta_x$ while controlling for the ARMA structure in the errors.

Already here we have a slight confusion: ARIMAX is not the same as regression with ARMA errors. If you are using, for example, `arima` function in R, you are fitting the latter. The model then looks like

\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + u_t \\
u_t &= \varphi_1 u_{t-1} + \dotsc + \varphi_p u_{t-p} + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \dotsc + + \theta_q \varepsilon_{t-q}
\end{aligned}

> In a second attempt, I modeled $y_t$ using a linear OLS model which includes $y_{t−1}, y_{t−2},\dotsc,y_{t−p}$ as lagged predictors.

That should look something like below

$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + \gamma_1 y_{t-1} + \dotsc + \gamma_p y_{t-p} + v_t. 
$$

Intuitively, if $x_t$ is correlated with a linear combination of the other regressors (lagged $y$s), inclusion of those regressors will change $\beta_1$, potentially a lot. Meanwhile, if $u_t$ is relatively well behaved, $\beta_1$ will be more or less what you would expect it to be in a simple regression $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_t+\epsilon_t$ with $\epsilon_t \sim i.i.d.(0,\sigma^2)$. This "intuition" is quite loose, though, and I don't know whether expecting $u_t$ to be well behaved is justified. For a reliable treatment, see the blog post cited above.

Also, your argumentation

> From a theoretical point, the OLS model with lagged predictors should produce similar results as an AR-model (neglecting optimizations issues). Hence the difference must lay in the MA-part of the ARIMA model (neglecting the differentiation for a moment)

becomes tangential once we recognize how different the two models actually are.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the link is indeed helpful.